# how to disable vibration from specific apps in android programmatically

Tags: android, vibration

Depends on [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and its method `cancelNotification`, I can cancel any notification that comes from specific app based on the package name.

But this method doesn't seem to stop the vibration of that notification when I use `cancelNotification`! Is there any way to disable the vibration of coming notifications? Or generally, can I stop the vibration of specific apps?

I've tried to convert the phone to silent mode, but this is too slow operation as the notification will be canceled, then vibration will be start, then the phone will be in silent mode!

```
    AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    aManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 20) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation text for setVibrateSetting() says:

This method should only be used by applications that replace the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application.
From what I understand, there is no other option to globally enable or disable vibration, so if you have an app such as a ring profile manager, you probably need to use it.

IMHO, Google used deprecation here inappropriately.

I use the following class to hide the deprecation in one "compat" class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
class AudioManagerCompat {
    final static int VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER = AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER;
    final static int VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION = AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION;
    final static int VIBRATE_SETTING_ON = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON;
    final static int VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF;
    final static int VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT = AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ONLY_SILENT;

    static int getVibrateSetting(AudioManager am, int vibrateType) {
        return am.getVibrateSetting(vibrateType);
    }

    static void setVibrateSetting(AudioManager am, int vibrateType, int vibrateSetting) {
        am.setVibrateSetting(vibrateType, vibrateSetting);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this code before, but I don't understand how can I use it? I've tried to use this but doesn't work `aManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);`